# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload validate file Type/Size validation on Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How to validate file Type/Size validation on (Asp.net) server side code  before save in folder. 
How to display server side error message?

```
 private void _UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = context.Request.Files[i]; if (!FileValidation(context.Request.Files[i]))
            {
                throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Attempt to upload chunked file containing more than one fragment per request");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried all possible scenario.but custom message is not display.

Comment: Can you post your code, so we can have a look at where you're going wrong

Comment: private void _UploadWholeFile (HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) 
        {
 for (var i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++){
     var file = context.Request.Files[i];
         if (!FileValidation(context.Request.Files[i])){
          throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Not Valid file type");
                }
                file.SaveAs(StorageRoot + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                var fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength));
            }
}

Comment: * In this code I am checking valid File type on my Handler.ashx file.but not getting my custom error message.

Comment: Can you format the code into your question please. It's very difficult to read it this way

Comment: So Could you please help me how to display custom error on Page??

Comment: private void _UploadWholeFile (HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = context.Request.Files[i];
                if (!FileValidation(context.Request.Files[i]))
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Attempt to upload chunked file containing more than one fragment per request");
                }

            }
  }

Comment: So you want to display error message to the end user on your asp page?

Comment: private void _UploadWholeFile (HttpContext context) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
           var file = context.Request.Files[i];

           if (!FileValidation(context.Request.Files[i]))
           {
             throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Please select valid file type");
           }
    if (!FileSizeValidation(context.Request.Files[i]))
           {
             throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Please select valid file Size");
           }
              
         }
}

Comment: Yes...Like File Type or File Size message.I want to display message using Server side code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but my question How to add validation code on my FileHandler.ashx file ?  I am using https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ plugin.